# Core plot not sizing the plot area appropriately for bar graph

Tags: iphone, charts, core-plot

I've got a container view that holds 2 view controllers, each of which in turn hosts a CPGraphHostingView. The heirarchy is something like this

ContainerView
      - TopView
      - BottomView

I initialize topViewController(initWithNibName), resize the view to 70% of the height and add the topViewController.view to  containerView subviews

Similarly for BottomView, except that the height is 30%

These 2 views now span the height of the container view.

However, the bar plot drawn in the bottom view does not respect the super views height coordinates and draws the bars out of range resulting in the need for a vertical scroll. I've also tried adjusting the plotScale post addition of graph, but causes me to lose some alignment.

Strangely, the scatter chart view in the top view seems to behave better and scales when i flip  the top: bottom ratio to 3:7 from the original 7:3.

Are bar plots supposed to behave differently ? Or am i missing something here. Attached are the images for my issue. notice that in both cases , the top scatter chart seems to have scaled correctly.

Also, i tested by using the scatter chart code in the bottomViewController (to make sure that this wasn't some nib issue) and again with scatter chart the scaling seems to just work.

Thanks a lot.

PS: i didn't use google groups because i could not post images there.
[image: bar chart does not scale to 30%]

[image: does not eve scale to 70% properly]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it works for the scatter plot makes me think there is an issue with the way your bar plot is set up.

Double-check your plot ranges in the plot space for the bar plot. The bars are being clipped because the `yRange` is too short and starts at a location above the minimum data value.